# Discordjs - Cannot send messages to this user

Tags: javascript

I am making a `discord.js` bot for a server I am in, but after attempting to send a DM to a user (who was just kicked, to notify them of it,) the bot won't send it at all and it will spit out an error,

> "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send
>   messages to this user"

its out of control now, because it will work, I'll add a small something, it will STOP working (more or less expected) and then when I revert that addition it will spit out the error again.

Here is my code for the kick command

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const Client = new Discord.Client
const prefix = "m!"

module.exports.run = async(bot, message, args) => {
params = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);

command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

let memberKick = message.mentions.members.first();

let reasonKick = args.slice(1).join(" ");

if(message.member.roles.find("name", "MedaFrost Controller")) {
    var userReslv = message.guild.members.find("id", memberKick.id);
    let usericon = memberKick.displayAvatarURL;
    let botembed = new Discord.RichEmbed
    botembed.setDescription("❌ You Were Kicked From Roscord!");
    botembed.setColor("FF0000");
    botembed.setThumbnail(usericon);
    botembed.addField("Reason:", `${reasonKick}`);
    userReslv.send(botembed);
    memberKick.kick(reasonKick);
    message.channel.send("✅ " + `${memberKick}` + " was kicked! ✅")
} else {
    const userId = message.member.id
    message.channel.send("Sorry, " + `<@${userId}>` + ", but you do not have sufficient permissions!")
}
}

module.exports.help = {
name: "kickplayer",
description: "Kicks mentioned user."
}
```

(Proof that the emoji is not the problem)
  [Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgUj4.png):

Comment: Maybe add a delay between the message and the actual kick?

Comment: I'm a bit of a dumbass, how would I go about doing that? 

Comment: Posted as an answer.

Comment: What is that `await(100)`?  Where is that coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding from the comments: Maybe add a delay between the message and the actual kick?

Since your function is `async`, it's a good idea to write a small `async` delay helper:

```
const delay = (msec) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, msec));
```

Now you can simply

```
userReslv.send(botembed);
await delay(100); // 100 msec = 0.1 seconds
memberKick.kick(reasonKick); 
// ...
```

Comment: Thank you! The world needs more people like you! (tbh) :D

Comment: Adding "random" delays to async code instead of working correctly with this async/await or Promise approach seems not to be a good practice. Please reconsider this.

Answer (score 9):

You should **not** be using delays or timers to solve this issue. Asynchronous calls in Discord.js return Promises, you should use those promises.

Promises are something that can basically turn your asynchronous workflow synchronous: when something happens -> do this.

This is the workflow:

1. Send a message to a GuildMember
2. Kick after the message is properly sent

Don't worry, they won't have time to react to the message as these actions will most likely happen instantaneously, thanks to Promises. There are no additional delays.

So basically:

```
GuildMember
  .createDM()
  .then((DMChannel) => {
    // We have now a channel ready.
    // Send the message.
    DMChannel
      .send(reason)
      .then(() => {
        // Message sent, time to kick.
        GuildMember.kick(reason);
      });
  });
```

[Here's the referenced GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember)

You can also catch, and you should. Catching happens when a Promise fails to execute the task it was assigned.

```
GuildMember
  .createDM()
  .then((DMChannel) => {
    // We have now a channel ready.
    // Send the message.
    DMChannel
      .send(reason)
      .then(() => {
        // Message sent, time to kick.
        GuildMember
          .kick(reason)
          .catch((e) => {
            console.log('Failed to kick!', e);
            // Do something else instead...
          });
      });
  });
```

(You can catch the message sending too, or creating the channel.)

Here you can learn more about Promises, which are an essential part of JavaScript: https://javascript.info/promise-basics

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a lot of the functions you are using are asynchronous.

Specifically:

- [`kick`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=kick)
- [`send`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=send)

Additionally, you are trying to `send` to a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember).  I'm not super familiar with this API, but I think they may be considered **not** a `GuildMember` anymore after you kick in which case the reference may be stale.  I think you should instead send directly to the [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User), after you `kick`.

Additionally, I don't think you are waiting enough in general.  `kick` and `send` both return `Promise`s which you should probably `await` to resolve, especially `kick`.

After you have that reference **then** use the `send` with the constructed message:

```js
async function kicker(bot, message, args) {
  /** @type GuildMember */
  const guildMemberToKick = message.mentions.members.first();

  /** @type User */
  const guildMemberUser = guildMemberToKick.user;

  /** @type RichEmbed */
  const kickRichMessage = new Discord.RichEmbed;

  /** @type String */
  const kickReason = "You've been a baaaad person";

  // Build the rich kick message
  kickRichMessage.setDescription("❌ You Were Kicked From Roscord!");
  kickRichMessage.setColor("FF0000");
  kickRichMessage.setThumbnail(guildMemberUser.displayAvatarURL);
  kickRichMessage.addField("Reason:", kickReason);

  // Kick and wait
  await guildMemberToKick.kick(kickReason);

  // Tell the user we kicked them and wait
  await guildMemberUser.send(kickRichMessage);

  // Tell the channel we kicked and wait
  await message.channel.send(`✅ ${guildMemberToKick.displayName} was kicked! ✅`);
}
```