# Discord.js custom emoji error it looks simple, but how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have Discord.js custom emoji error it looks simple, but how do I fix it?
I want custom emojis on embed, it works. But when I react to the custom emoji, bot doesn't send me anything to PM.

**I get answer only from the card emoji.**

```
Error: (node:20548) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user
    at RequestHandler.execute (d:\Users\Pc\Desktop\Musu botai\Donate\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:170:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction,user) => {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === '706559022286897302') {
        user.send(direktas)
    } else if (reaction.emoji.name === '706754740767424572') {
        user.send("ssss esi")
        
    } else if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
        user.send("dddd")
        
    }

});
client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51407473/discordjs-cannot-send-messages-to-this-user)

Your bot is sending messages to quickly, and needs a delay. You could do this by using `setTimeout()`

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    user.send("ssss esi")
}, 1000) // 1000 millisecond delay (1 second)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the names of these emojis actually those strings? I think you're looking that the IDs here. If so, you might want to try `reaction.emoji.id == 'EMOJI_ID'`.